# How to prove the problem is in NP?

Tags: graph-theory, np-complete

We have:

Convering by triples

Data: A set Y of cardinality 3n and a family C = ($C_{1},...C_{m}$) of triples of elements of Y: for all i, $C_{i}$ $\subset Y$ and |$C_{i}$| = 3.

Problem: Is there a subset $C^{'}$ of C which forms a partition of Y: i.e. such that the element of $C^{'}$ are pairwise distinct and the union of $C^{'}$ is Y?

Prove that the problem is in NP.

Please help me how to prove it?, thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that the input involves both $Y$ and $C$, so "polynomial" amounts to polynomial in $n+m$. With that observation, the problem is clearly in NP because, when the answer is "yes", the partition $C'$ serves as a witness that can be checked in polynomial time. (By the way, you probably meant "pairwise disjoint" rather than "pairwise distinct", but the problem is in NP for the same reason in either case.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all this problem is equivalent to the following:
In a graph with m nodes, find a set of n nodes that do not neighbor each other on the graph. As it should not be too hard to show that the latter reduces to the former, and the former reduces to the latter.

Then you can take the complement of the above graph $G^c$, and your problem is equivalent to finding if there is a fully connected subgraph with n nodes. If you can solve that, you can solve the maximum clique problem, which is known to be NPC. And huraay, we are done